# what does effei mean, and where is it from?

Tags: phrases, loanwords, origin-unknown

I'm not a native English speaker, but i think you'll understand me.
I've recently seen a billboard that had a word like "effei" in it, so I googled it. The effei seems to stand for European Federation of Financial Executives Institutes, but also, I've found [this link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Effei):

> Effei is a beautiful person in body and soul. Effei is seen as weird and different before truely getting to know her but she is someone you would rather have as a friend than an enemy. When Effei is in live she will give it all to the person of interest. Effei will always put her friends before herself making her the ideal listener.
>   *Effei wanted to go on a date with her boyfriend but her friend needed advice so she had to stay and help*

So, my questions are: Does this word exist in English? If not, could it be from another language, or is it just a made up word? If, again, not, is there an English word that encapsulates the described person? If not in English, is there a, lets say, a Latin word for it? Note that I said "Latin" instead of "any other language", and by "Latin" I mean: Any phrase/name/synonym for that kind of a person.

Comment: Is it all lower case or is it all upper (eg. EFFEI)? What was the context of the billboard? As a note, the Urban Dictionary is a place for words/phrases and their definitions that are often slang. If you see the thumbs up/down, that's how many people agree that this is a good definition for the word. The definition of "Effei" on UD has no up or down votes, which means it's not likely a real word, even from their point of view. I've never personally heard of it.

Comment: Your primary dictionary should not be a slang dictionary. I would recommend Webster's, American Heritage, or Oxford's as definitive dictionaries of the English language.

Answer (score 4):

Did the word on the billboard look like this?
[image: EFFEI_1]

— then it's the European Federation of Financial Executives Institutes.

Or did it look like this?
[image: EFFEI_2]

— then it's an Italian circuit board manufacturer.

*Effei* in the Urban Dictionary citation is obviously a person's name or sobriquet, not an ordinary word. The contributor is using UD to communicate with her or with their friends.

UD is a great source for seeing its contributors in their on-line personae and studying how they think and express themselves; and if you've got an ear for its peculiar dialect and genre and can tell what's real and what's spoof or personal in-jokes, it can be of some value in its ostensible role as a dictionary.

But these virtues are not usually what learners are looking for when they consult a dictionary. Abstain: it's only going to confuse you.